# How to make my dot product method in Java faster or more efficient?

Tags: java, optimization, matrix, dot-product

I have a small Java method that is used to perform a dot product between an input vector and a matrix. Here is the code:

```
    public void calcOutput() {
    outputs = new float[output];
    float sum = 0F;

    for(int j = 0; j < output; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            sum += inputs[i] * weights[j][i];
        }

        outputs[j] = sum;
    }
}
```

Basically what this is supposed to do is take my input vector 'inputs' and perform a dot product with a matrix I have named "weights". The output is then placed in an output vector, 'outputs'.

How can I make this faster or more efficient? My weight matrix also does not need to be a matrix if that helps. I just need a way to easily access the corresponding index.

Thanks

Comment: Have you benchmarked this code? Why do you think it can be more efficient?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, it runs around 30-40ms given large input and output numbers and a large weight matrix.

Comment: You might be able to make it fractionally faster by reversing the outer and inner loops, to reduce the number of accesses to the `inputs` vector.  I'll write an answer later if I have time.

Comment: Is the same `weights` values used for multiple calls to this method?

Comment: It may help to use multiple accumulators, that's something that has to be done for good performance but the JIT compiler may be scared to do it since it changes the result slightly.

Comment: Offhand, I would expect the indexing calculation of `weights[j][i]` to be the costly point, and it depends on how `weights` is declared. If all the elements of `weight[j]` are contiguous, then outside the inner loop you could set a pointer to that. Beyond that, the inner loop could be unrolled some. I know people will flame at this and say the optimizer should take care of all that, but in my experience you can't depend on it.

Comment: @Seephor - Please don't "correct" the errors in the code your question.  It invalidates answers.

Comment: @StephenC I made 1 correction to moving the sum in the right place, the asking question is still valid and left it at that.

Comment: @Bohemian the weights matrix is initialized with random values outside the scope of this method in the object class's constructor, and this method is only called once per the class that contains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't anything better. It's the simplest method you can implement and the algorithm follows good memory caching approach, i.e. the outer loop follows outer index of the array and the inner loop loops over the elements within one subarray.

Maybe it could help to use temporary variable for the inner array but I guess JIT will take care of this.

Additionally, there is a mistake, the `sum` variable should be in scope of the outer loop, not the method scope. It needs to be reset with every iteration of the outer loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < output; j++) {
    // NOTE the line:
    float sum = 0;
    // and the reference to inner array:
    byte[] row = weights[j];
    for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        sum += inputs[i] * row[i];
    }

    outputs[j] = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches much better than writing a vanilla dot product. The naive implementation will get vectorised by C2, but the sequential reduction phase is so slow that the benefits of the vectorised multiplication are cancelled out. In Java right now (JDK10), the best thing you can do is to unroll using partial sums to break data dependencies. C2 will emit scalar code, but it will use some pipelining and you can get up to 4 flops/cycle.

```
float s0 = 0f;
float s1 = 0f;
float s2 = 0f;
float s3 = 0f;
float s4 = 0f;
float s5 = 0f;
float s6 = 0f;
float s7 = 0f;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8) {
  s0 = Math.fma(left[i + 0],  right[i + 0], s0);
  s1 = Math.fma(left[i + 1],  right[i + 1], s1);
  s2 = Math.fma(left[i + 2],  right[i + 2], s2);
  s3 = Math.fma(left[i + 3],  right[i + 3], s3);
  s4 = Math.fma(left[i + 4],  right[i + 4], s4);
  s5 = Math.fma(left[i + 5],  right[i + 5], s5);
  s6 = Math.fma(left[i + 6],  right[i + 6], s6);
  s7 = Math.fma(left[i + 7],  right[i + 7], s7);
}
return s0 + s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7;
```

To go as fast as possible, you need explicit vectorisation with accumulators. Code like this can be written with the Project Panama Vector API.

```
var sum1 = YMM_FLOAT.zero();
var sum2 = YMM_FLOAT.zero();
var sum3 = YMM_FLOAT.zero();
var sum4 = YMM_FLOAT.zero();
int width = YMM_FLOAT.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += width * 4) {
  sum1 = YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(left, i).fma(YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(right, i), sum1);
  sum2 = YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(left, i + width).fma(YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(right, i + width), sum2);
  sum3 = YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(left, i + width * 2).fma(YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(right, i + width * 2), sum3);
  sum4 = YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(left, i + width * 3).fma(YMM_FLOAT.fromArray(right, i + width * 3), sum4);
}
return sum1.addAll() + sum2.addAll() + sum3.addAll() + sum4.addAll();
```

See this [blog post](http://richardstartin.uk/vector-api-dot-product/) for benchmarks and in depth analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.  By reversing the outer and inner loops, you can reduce the number of lookups in the `inputs` array.  Also, you don't need the `sum` variable - you can just do your addition directly in the `outputs` array.

```
    float[] outputs = new float[output];

    for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        float inputsI = inputs[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < output; j++) {
            outputs[j] += inputsI * weights[j][i];
        }

    }
```

I would expect this to be only a tiny bit faster.  In almost all real-world applications, it's not worth worrying about tiny, tiny optimisations such as this one.